# OpenCV accept HTTP video streaming with different endpoints

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am writing a server, which receives live video stream over HTTP and performs some operations for different endpoints.

I am using `OpenCV` for that and my basic code looks somethings like this

```
void f1()
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap("http://localhost:8080/operation1");
    if (!cap.isOpened())
        return;

    for (;;)
    {
        cv::Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;

        // do something
    }
}

void f2()
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap("http://localhost:8080/operation2");
    if (!cap.isOpened())
        return;

    for (;;)
    {
        cv::Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;

        // do something else
    }
}

void f3() {...}
```

As you see each function listens to a different HTTP endpoint and does different operation. Each function runs in a separate thread.

The problem is that for some reason `OpenCV` ignores the resource part in endpoint i.e. if `ip:port` is correct it will accept the stream no matter it is from `operation1` or `operation2`.

For testing purposes I use this command as a stream generator
`ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -listen 1 -f matroska -c:v libx264 -preset fast -tune zerolatency  http://localhost:8080/operation1`

How can I make `OpenCV` to differentiate between HTTP endpoints? What am I missing? I have no any previous experience with `OpenCV` and photo/video stuff.

Comment: Can you access both streams simultaneously using ffplay?

Comment: No. If one function accesses to stream, others do not.